Any commutative ring with all elements satisfying $r=r^2$ is isomorphic to the Cartesian Product of $F_2$
How do I prove that any commutative ring $R$ with every element equal to its square has to be isomorphic to the Cartesian Product of some number of the finite field of order $2$?
I tried inducting on the order of $R$, but I don’t think I used the right argument.

Have you proved yet that $x+x=0$ in such a ring? If not, consider what you know about $(1+x)^2$.

Actually, I'm not sure this is true? Consider the ring of functions $f:\mathbb N\to F_2$ such that the function is constant everywhere except for at finitely many points. So, where either $f^{-1}(0)$ is finite or $f^{-1}(1)$ is finite.  Show $f+g$ and $fg$ must have this property if $f,g$ have this property. Then this ring is infinite but countable, and your theorem can't have a product of $F_2$ countable,

You can definitely show that it must be isomorphic to a sum of $F_2$ fields, but not necessarily a product. You can show it is a sum by first showing it is a vector space over $F_2,$ and then finding a basis. (The existence of the basis is would require the Axiom of Choice, however.)

The claim is wrong. Please fix it, and provide some context. Search for "classification of boolean rings" and related search terms.

You’re right, I made a stupid claim. I will thereby close this question.
